# how to get combined data of 2 nodes using a single for each loop with same dtasnapshot object

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: screenshot]

I need to display list of all users (Name, date and status) in a single list where status="Leave Pending" as pointed by red arrow. I wrote the following code to do this but it is not giving me  username in the list.

[image: screenshot]

As I used nested for each loop for this but not getting username. Kindly suggest me some solution to display the username too.

In my code:

1. LeaveRequestsInfo is the model class for mapping  data.
2. requestsInfo is the object of modal class in which i am mapping my data.
3. listViewRequests is the ListView
4. requestsList is the object of List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, you need to query the database twice, once to get the user id and second, based on that id to get the name of the user. This can be done in a very simple way, using the String class, so please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference attendanceRef = rootRef.child("Attendance");
Query query = attendanceRef.orderByChild("status").equalsTo("Leave Pending");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String id = ds.child("id").getValue(String.class);

            DatabaseReference idRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(id);
            ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                    Log.d("TAG", name);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            };
            idRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The result in your logcat will be all the names of all attendances where the status is `Leave Pending`.